# How do we consume rest api with Http basic authentication in spring?

Tags: java, rest

I want to consume rest api from url with http basic authentication that returns a big json & then i want to parse that json without POJO to get some values out of it. How can i achieve that in java spring?

I know this is common question but i could not get proper solution that worked for me.

Please help me someone.

Comment: Your question is not clear could you please elaborate your question. As per my understanding you can do that way  
```ResponseEntity<String> result = ......Your restTemplate
 JSONObject arr = new JSONObject((result));
 
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
          JSONObject abc = arr.getJSONObject(i);
          System.out.println("test1 : " + abc.getString("test1"));
          System.out.println("test2 : " + abc.getString("test2"));
          System.out.println("test3 : " + abc.getString("test3"));
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Apache HttpClient, the following Client Code snipped has been copied from the following URL. The comments have been added by myself.

https://www.baeldung.com/httpclient-4-basic-authentication

```
HttpGet request = new HttpGet(URL_SECURED_BY_BASIC_AUTHENTICATION);

// Combine the user and password pair into the right format
String auth = DEFAULT_USER + ":" + DEFAULT_PASS;

// Encode the user-password pair string in Base64
byte[] encodedAuth = Base64.encodeBase64(
  auth.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1));

// Build the header String "Basic [Base64 encoded String]"
String authHeader = "Basic " + new String(encodedAuth);

// Set the created header string as actual header in your request
request.setHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, authHeader);

HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
assertThat(statusCode, equalTo(HttpStatus.SC_OK));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ;)

Does this response contain json response ?

Comment: This code snipped is executing a simple HTTP GET request. The response is, whatever the remote server does return.